# UWSGI logrotation

Tags: uwsgi, logrotate

I have running uwsgi server. i need log rotation for daily and file size based log rotation.

uwsgi configuration:

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
description "uWSGI starter"

start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

# home - is the path to our virtualenv directory
# pythonpath - the path to our django application
# module - the wsgi handler python script

exec /home/testuser/virtual_environments/teatapp/bin/uwsgi \
--uid testuser \
--home /home/testuser/virtual_environments/teatapp \
--pythonpath /home/testuser/sci-github/teatapp\
--socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock \
--chmod-socket \
--module wsgi \
--logdate \
--optimize 2 \
--processes 2 \
--master \
--logto /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
```

logrotate configuration:

```
# file : /etc/logrotate.conf

"/var/log/uwsgi/*.log" {
    copytruncate
    daily
    maxsize 5k
    dateext
    rotate 5
    compress
    missingok
    create 777 root root
}
```

But log rotation is not working please give the solution for if any wrong configuration in logrotaion.conf.

Comment: Have you found good solution?

Answer (score 2):

there is logrotation in uwsgi, based on the log file size, for example (uwsgi.ini directive):

```
log-maxsize = 100000
```

if you want to use logrotated, you have to restart uwsgi (logrotate directives):

```
postrotate
           stop uwsgi
           start uwsgi
endscript
```

Comment: The `log-maxsize` ini directive is documented at [uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#log-maxsize)

Answer (score 2):

It's not needed to restart `uwsgi` service if you use `copytruncate` option in `logrotate` file (as stated by Tamar).

But the problem may be that you forgot to enable `logrotate` in `cron`. Please, make sure you have a entry in `/etc/cron.daily` called `logrotate`.

Answer (score -4):

Just put this on your uwsgi configuration file :

daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log

This will create a log each day, but be carefull don't daemonize if you are using master our emperror. Then if the logs are big you can control it with a script attatched to a cron to clean the folder.

Comment: This simply creates a log with a date in it, but does not rotate it.  I've tried this using uwsgi 2.0.12.  I set my clock to 23:59:00, fired up uwsgi, used the website for a few minutes.  No new file is created after 00:00:00, all logs continue to go to the previous day.  I also saw somewhere to use log-reopen = true, this also has no effect.