# UWSGI log rotation gets error: “parent directory has insecure permissions”

Tags: permissions, uwsgi, logrotate

I would like to rotate the logs of UWSGI and here is my config file:

```
/var/log/uwsgi.log {
        size 100M
        missingok
        rotate 400
        dateext
        dateformat .%Y%m%d-%s
        compress
        notifempty
        create
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
           stop uwsgi
           start uwsgi
        endscript
}
```

but I get the following error when I try to rotate it:

```
error: skipping "/var/log/uwsgi.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
```

the permissions of the file are as follows:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 33201346 Oct 10 10:32 /var/log/uwsgi.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 281 Oct 10 10:20 /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi
```

So I don't see any reason to use the 'su' directive. Can anybody tell me what's wrong here? I'm also not sure if I need to restart it every time I rotate the logs ( I borrow it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446713/uwsgi-logrotation)). and My config file looks the same as these examples ([1](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/uwsgi/rotate-log-daily-for-uwsgi-with-logrotate/)except the create permissions, I'm not sure if it matters), [2](https://github.com/jbq/uwsgi/blob/master/debian/uwsgi.logrotate), [3](https://github.com/vortex-rpm/uwsgi/blob/master/SOURCES/uwsgi.logrotate)(except the postrotate),[5](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2015-September/008155.html) (I don't use copy truncate, as the log files are big), [6](https://superuser.com/questions/867857/uwsgi-how-to-keep-log-file-size-contained) none of these solutions has permission problem.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that parent directory has correct permissions

```
chmod 755 /var/log/ && chown root:root /var/log/
chmod 755 /var && chown root:root /var
```

You should probably try setting create permissions in your config file to something like

```
create 777 root root
```

if none of above works use `su root syslog` in the config

Comment: why would you su root syslog when you just set the owner/group to root:root?